# Using isparta with karma with webpacked module app

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, isparta

I'm trying to have test coverage on my ES2015 angular code.

My webapp is generated by gulp-angular, which provides by default a task that uses webpack to bundle all my angular modules in one file using the babel transpiler to generate ES5 code.

So for the moment, when I try to have code coverage, I only have it on my ES5 code and on one file (the bundle one).

I'd like to have it on my ES2015 code and on multiple file, not on the generated one. Knowing that my test task first launch the task to bundle the app then uses the generated file to launch the test, I'd like to know if it's possible to get what I want in that state? (or maybe I can't use webpack in that case?)